# What are the differences between a career in clinical psychology vs psychiatry?

Tags: clinical-psychology, medication

Hey everyone I need help, I’m kind of in a difficult situation right now. I’m currently doing a bachelor's degree in psychology and am really enjoying it. The degree includes clinical psychology so technically by the end of it I could apply to become a clinical psychologist. But recently I’ve been thinking I really like the more science and prescription/medicine aspects of psychology. More practical aspects as opposed to the more emotional 'therapy session' situations. Like maybe something more similar to psychiatry or physician fields which would require studying a 5 year medicine degree. I feel very stressed out because this psychology degree is already 3 years and i feel like it would be crazy to go into medicine after this… or would it?? I don't know, I just need help because I don’t know the most simple way I could do this. I'd also like to know if I could potentially still be able to do things other than just therapy if I stuck with clinical psychology? I don't know enough about it.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question sounds like advice-seeking (self-help) which unfortunately, we are not really set up for.  If you are interested in differences between types of clinicians, then it might help to specify the jurisdiction, as the rules for me here in [Ontario](https://www.hamiltonpsych.ca/faq.html#difference) may differ from states in the US, or UK countries.  The same if you are interested in a research-oriented career, or some other applied psychology option.  Probably asking to list out all the career options available to you would be too broad of a question for us here.